# Do these sentences below mean the same?

Tags: meaning

I'd like to know whether two sentences below convey the same meaning.

- Students who are in the next seat in class are likely to be friends faster.
- Students who sit next to each other in class are likely to be friends faster.

Comment: The first one doesn't really make sense because it's not clear what "next" refers to.  From your question, I can see that you mean "next to each other", but "next" by itself doesn't mean that.

Comment: To be clear, stangdon means the first sentence should read, "Students who are in seats next to each other...". Also, it should be "become", rather than "be" as it's a process over time.

Answer (score 1):

> Students who sit next to each other in class are likely to be friends
> faster.

This is ok, although since this about the process of forming friendship I would use this:

- Students who sit next to each other in class are likely to become friends faster.

> Students who are in the next seat in class are likely to be friends faster.

Although the meaning is clear, 'the next seat' is singular but 'students' is plural.  You could use:

- Students in adjacent seats in class are likely to become friends faster.

Answer (score 0):

I find the very word 'next' shrouded in ambiguity here  with its failure in fixing on a precise location, so why not use phrases such as 'in close proximity' instead to make the sentence more meaningful and less ambiguous by saying "Students who are in close proximity in class are likely to be /make friends faster".